# Will corruption/hallows destroy mud-based life?

Tags: terraria

Once a world enters hardmode, corruption and hallows being spreading at an alarming rate, including the underground. Grass, which grows on dirt, succumbs easily to both. Jungles and glowing mushrooms grow on mud and provide unique and valuable items. Will corruption/hallows destroy these if left unchecked? If they do destroy mud-based life, how can I preserve these fragile ecosystems?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Hallow can spread onto mud, but corruption converts mud to dirt. So corruption will destroy everything, but hallow won't, so you best get come holy water and splash it all over your jungle and glowing mushroom farms. That said, I haven't played in a long time, so I'm not 100% on this information, maybe about 80%.

Comment: Corruption will convert mud to dirt, but it won't grow corruption grass on any level too deep for regular grass. So the surface jungle will eventually be destroyed completely, but underground jungle and glowing mushroom farms should lose some areas to dirt at the edges, but then shrink no further.

Comment: @Fambida have you considered posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corruption will convert mud to dirt, but it won't grow corruption grass on any level too deep for regular grass. So the surface jungle will eventually be destroyed completely, but underground jungle and glowing mushroom farms should lose some areas to dirt at the edges, but then shrink no further.

Answer (score 0):

corruption and crimson can and will infect mud and turn it to dirt but hallow never spreads to mud so surround mud based biomes with hallow using hallowed seeds, holy water or the clentaminator