# Can the Hallow destroy a jungle biome?

Tags: terraria

I have a world that has just transitioned into hard-mode. Stripes of Hallow and Corruption have both appeared in the world (as I expected), but the Hallow appeared right in the middle of my jungle biome (it even surrounds the Jungle Temple!).

Will the Hallow eventually destroy the jungle? I'm concerned that I won't be able to fight Plantera if it takes over the underground jungle quickly enough.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80040/will-corruption-hallows-destroy-mud-based-life

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

Hallow can't take over jungle. The corruption DOES take your jungle over, so be aware of underground corruption slowly eating your jungle.